# Angular 2 System is undefined error

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, gulp

I have an [Angular 2 project on github](https://github.com/Condra963/Angular2Test) and when i run it with npm start it gives "System is undefined". I use systemjsbuilder, did i do something wrong? Incorrect paths, incorrect order of build? Missing items? I followed the Angular 2 start but i tried to integrated in my own project with own order of paths. Maybe i did something wrong?

I think i oversee something when i follow the angular tutorial. Or is miss something when i try to use gulp with it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the community to efficiently help you.  Also provide code snippets of what you've changed, and/or have already tried in order to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with code.

You must first run

> npm install

and then

> npm start

It works perfectly fine for me.